# active class is missing when we revisit page which has swiper

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using 'angular2-useful-swiper' & swiper in my angular 6 application, that is working fine it does add style and active class to swipder slider class automatically, but when I visit other page and when I came back to swiper i see active and other css which gets appended to swiper slider class is missing and when I click on next arrow it does not rotate properly, I mean sometime I see half of current slide and half of other next slide in one content.  I tried..

```
config: SwiperOptions = {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: false,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 30,
        preventClicks:false,
        preventClicksPropagation:false
    };
```

but it does not work anyways, please help on this. below is the code from chrome inspector tool which works when active class and style added automatically using swiper.js
[chrome inspector snapshot of working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHg3m.png)

Comment: It works only when page referesh, if we revisit the page which has swiper functionality it does not work as I stated above.

Comment: `angular2-useful-swiper` [is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper), please consider using [a more modern library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-useful-swiper)